# Want to merge 2 rows with nearly the same time index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

So I'm working on a script in python using pandas where I sometimes get an output that looks like this:

| Time index | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19:30 | 5 | 0 |
| 21:30 | 4 | 0 |
| 21:31 | "NaN" | 1 |
| 23:30 | 4 | 0 |

Basically the 21:30/21:31 values correspond to each other but are misplaced due to faulty sensors or rounding errors. I was wondering if anyone know of a way to merge two rows when their time indexes are so similar (so within a minute of one another)? This would look as following:

| Time index | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19:30 | 5 | 0 |
| 21:30 | 4 | 1 |
| 23:30 | 4 | 0 |

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom group with aggregation to first/max:

```
# form new group if diff > 2min
m = ~pd.to_datetime(df['Time index']).diff().le('2min')

# aggregate all columns with max except "Time index"
agg_f = {c: 'max' for c in df}
agg_f['Time index'] = 'first'

# groupby + aggregation
out = df.groupby(m.cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(agg_f)
```

*NB. assuming NaN is a real NaN, else replace as first step: `.replace({'"NaN"', pd.NA})`.*

output:

```
  Time index  Value 1  Value 2
0      19:30      5.0        0
1      21:30      4.0        1
2      23:30      4.0        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
#Create dict by unique time, where time is key and set two list as zero
df_dic = {i[0]:[0,0] for i in [row.tolist() for i, row in df.iterrows()]}

#running the loop over df rows 
#compare the values of dict and df by time if its bigger then update
for i in [row.tolist() for i, row in df.iterrows()]:
    for j in range(1,len(i)):
        if i[j] > df_dic[i[0]][j-1]:
            df_dic[i[0]][j-1] = i[j]

#Convert dict to list and list to DF
pd.DataFrame([sum([[k],v],[]) for k,v in df_dic.items()],columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   Timeindex    Value 1 Value 2
0   19:30           5.0     0.0
1   21:30           4.0     1.0
3   23:30           4.0     0.0
```